# Get value of dictionary element and used in where condition in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dictionary

I have a SQL table (`Product`) like this:

```
+----+---------+---------+------+----------------+
| ID |CompanyID|   Name  | Code |  VisibleFields |
+----+---------+---------+------+----------------+
| 1  |   11    |    A    |  C1  |      ,1,2,     |
+----+---------+---------+------+----------------+
| 2  |   22    |    B    |  C2  |      ,2,       |
+----+---------+---------+------+----------------+
```

And a `enum`:

```
public enum Enum_ProductField
        {                             
            Name = 1,
            Code = 2                
        }
```

I used this `enum` in this method:

```
public override List<Product> GetListProducts(string Name,string Code)
        {                             
            string Name_F = "," + ((int)Product.Enum_ProductField.Name).ToString() + ",";
            string Code_F = "," + ((int)Product.Enum_ProductField.Code).ToString() + ",";

            List<Product> retVal = null;
            using (MarketEntities db = new MarketEntities())
            {              
                retVal = (from P in db.Products
                          where                                
                             (Code == string.Empty || (P.Code == Code && P.VisibleFields.Contains(Code_F))) &&
                             (Name == string.Empty || (P.Name.Contains(Name) && P.VisibleFields.Contains(Name_F)))
                          select P).ToList();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

If I call `GetListProducts("A", string.empty)` return product with `ID = 1`.

If I call `GetListProducts("B", string.Empty)` return null because `VisibleFields` of product with `ID = 2` does not exist `,1,` and it should not be displayed.

I want to change `GetListProducts` method and use a `Dictionary` for `enum` like this:

**1- Create Dictionary in `GetProductFieldAsDictionary`**

```
public static Dictionary<T, string> GetProductFieldAsDictionary<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            var visibleFieldsValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToDictionary(e => e, e => "," + ((int)(object)e).ToString() + ",");
            return visibleFieldsValues;
        }
```

This method gets a `enum`and return all visible fields with `Key` and `Value`.

**2- Use `GetProductFieldAsDictionary` in query**

```
public override List<Product> GetListProducts(string Name, string Code)
        {           
            var _ProductFields = ISTIUtility.GetProductFieldAsDictionary<Product.Enum_ProductField>();            

            List<Product> retVal = null;
            using (MarketEntities db = new MarketEntities())
            {              
                retVal = (from P in db.Products
                          where
                             (Code == string.Empty || (P.Code == Code && P.VisibleFields.Contains(_ProductFields[Product.Enum_ProductField.Code]))) &&
                             (Name == string.Empty || (P.Name.Contains(Name) && P.VisibleFields.Contains(_ProductFields[Product.Enum_ProductField.Name])))
                          select P).ToList();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

But I get `Run-time error` because I can't use `Dictionary` in `linq` like code above.

> I do not want to get value of `Dictionary` out of the `linq query`.

I read a lot of posts, but I did not find a solution for it. Is there any way to do use this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to do same way you did it before - declare variable, assign it from dictionary and use it in query.

```
public override List<Product> GetListProducts(string Name, string Code)
{           
   var _ProductFields = ISTIUtility.GetProductFieldAsDictionary<Product.Enum_ProductField>();            

   string Name_F = _ProductFields[Product.Enum_ProductField.Name];
   string Code_F = _ProductFields[Product.Enum_ProductField.Code];
   List<Product> retVal = null;
   using (Irandnn_HypermarketEntities db = new Irandnn_HypermarketEntities())
   {              
     retVal = (from P in db.Products
               where
               (Code == string.Empty || (P.Code == Code && P.VisibleFields.Contains(Code_F))) &&
               (Name == string.Empty || (P.Name.Contains(Name) && P.VisibleFields.Contains(Name_F )))
               select P).ToList();
   }
   return retVal;
}
```

The point here that in linq do not know how to convert dictionary variable to SQL query, but it knows how to convert string.

Comment: I want to do it in `linq` query. Otherwise I can do it in old way that I do not need a dictionary !!!.

Comment: Please see Title of question. I want to do it in `Where condition`.

Comment: Your title is not saying that you want to use Dictionary directly in query, so...ok I won't try to get in deep discussions, so the answer is there is NO simple solution. Maybe you can do it by writing custom expression, bet I don't see the problem in your case to do so.

Comment: Ok I edited question and I added `I do not want to get value of Dictionary out of the linq query`.